# Abort request while navigating away from the component in React Native

Tags: react-native, promise, cancellation

I am using RN, redux and react-native-router-flux. One of my components is making an API request. I want to know whether is there an option to abort the request when the user navigates to another page (if the request is not finished yet).

Comment: if you think about it, once a request is sent to a server there's no way to take it back - more details in the question (like why and what's the problem if you don't abort) would be useful

Comment: I guess yes, it can be already sent to the server. I want to use abort/cancel option here, for example, to use it when the request is taking much time than usual and you want to cancel it and then request it again or do anything else